# Запуск lubuntu без графического интерфейса

Tags: linux, lubuntu

Суть: необходимо запускать lubuntu без графического окружения. Как это сделать?
И производить старт xserver только после логина для определённых пользователей (старт xserver указывается в скрипте авторизации конкретного пользователя).

Comment: Теоретически — запретить старт сервиса менежера дисплея (кто он там в лубунте? xdm, lightdm?), а в .bashrc или сходном у нужных пользователей запускать startx. Только надо проверять, зашёл ли пользователь с консоли (ttyX), чтобы не дёргать иксы при удалённом заходе.

Comment: Основная задача дистрибутива lubuntu - предоставить пользователю возможность работать с системой посредством оболочки lxde (или lxqt). Если вам на постоянной основе графическая оболочка не нужна, то вы выбрали неправильный дистрибутив. Используйте ubuntu server или arch linux.

Comment: runleve 3 как вариант